# Adobe Embed API - how to add annotations using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, adobe-embed-api

I would like to add a box over a specified area of a PDF using Javascript and Adobe Embed API. The documentation is not clear on how to do this. I have page coordinates of where box should be placed, has anyone had success in doing this?

Comment: ah apologies, I think I have used the wrong term. I would just like to draw a box over text using coordinates

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, I'll give this a try in the way you suggested :)

Comment: I'm confused - what comment gave you detailed info? Did you figure it out?

Comment: Hey Raymond, looks like the comment I responded to has been deleted

Comment: Boggle. Well, let me know if you need more help!